# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk: Can multiple applications share a single Amazon RDS database instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When creating an application in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, you have the option of creating a new Amazon RDS database instance.  Is it possible to associate an existing RDS database instance with an Elastic Beanstalk application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to share an RDS instance between multiple applications, the best thing to do is set that up independent of your beanstalk application.

Set up privs for each application and configure each application to use the RDS instance.

You will probably have to manually configure your application security group to access the database instance.

Comment: I've associated each application security group with the shared RDS instance.  But the application still points to an independent database endpoint. I don't see a way to configure that.

Comment: Julian, see this document: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python.rds.html

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue and fixed using following steps :

1) Go to EC2 instance and note your security group example "sg-121212121212"

2) Go to RDS Security Group ad=nd inbound traffic

3) Edit rule select all traffic and add your new ebs security group "sg-121212121212"

Hope it will helpful

Answer (score -1):

A single database can only be used with one Elastic Beanstalk environment. Although, it can be moved between environments. 
Also important to remember that a clone operation doesn't clone the database.